# Weird positioning in IE8 when hovering

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-float, positioning

I have a collection of divs in the layout shown in the image. All four divs (A, B, C, D) are floated left and each have a link elements inside of them wrapping other content elements (mostly divs and images but some text as well)

[image]

The problem is that in IE8, when you hover over items B, C or D, the item you hover over drops down 100px or so. If you hover on B it pushes C and D down. If you hover on D, just D drops down.

It is only a problem in actual IE8, not IE9 in IE8 mode.

Has anyone come across this behaviour befor with links inside floated elements?

There is a ton of CSS, but I am using a standard clearfix on the content inside the floated containers. The widths and heights of the containers are % based, some of the elements inside have fixed px widths

Comment: Can you provide your CSS or a link to the page in question?

Comment: It was actually a fixed pixel width on one of the elements inside B that was causing the problem. Weirdly it caused the issue with block D, even though block D itself contained no elements with fixed widths :S man I hate IE...

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell the root problem. One thing you could do is add additional styles to your div on hover, which would prevent them from expanding.

```
#B:hover{height:200px;}
#C:hover{height:200px;}
#D:hover{height:200px;}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't use a fixed height, but I tried adding a max-height and it hasn't helped. It's like the content 'falls out' of the container when you hover on it, when I inspect it in the dev tools, the blue outline showing where it 'thinks' the element is is still in the correct place

Comment: Is your page live? Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: It's not live yet unfortunately. Making a fiddle would take hours to do because of the complexity of the rest of the page and other styles. I'll see if I can replicate just this bit and make a fiddle...